# problem with merging/adding multiple elements in Linked List in the same index (JAVA)

Tags: java, indexing, linked-list

Hi i have a problem with this:

I want to get a book title(String) and release date(int) in the same index,
but is it posible to do that? 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a new Book object with fields title and year

```
Public Class Book{
   private String title;
   private int year;

   public Book(String title, int year){
     this.title = title;
     this.year= year;
   }

   public String getTitle(){
      return title;
   }
   public int getYear(){
      return year;
   }
}
```

And then store it in the list

```
LinkedList<Book> list = new LinkedList<Book>();
```

this way you can access all the book info with the index

```
Book book = list.get(2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! and if I need to make for-each loop and print these books that are under year 2000?

Comment: the most compact and readeble way if you are using jdk 8 or above is use the stream API. So you can do something like this:

list.stream().filter(book -> book.getYear() == 2000).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Ok, and I get this: com.company.Book@133314b
com.company.Book@b1bc7ed
com.company.Book@7cd84586
com.company.Book@30dae81
com.company.Book@1b2c6ec2

Comment: First of all you have to know how do you want to display the book. When you try to display an object java bydefault use that annotation. If you want to display for example: "Ttile (year)" you have to override toString method of the class: 

@Override
  public String toString() {
    return title+" ("+year+")";
  }